# Using jQuery Advanced Structured Filter Plugin in PHP with POST data

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery Advanced Structured Filter Plugin to filter data in PHP. With AJAX, I am able to filter, but I want to filter data by submit the form to show pagination on list without removing applied filter. Also I have to preserve sorting order on searching or pagination. Please suggest any solution or other option to filter data like this plugin if available.

Here is the link to advance filter plugin which i am using:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/advanced-structured-filter.html

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/advanced-structured-filter/